# Objective-C: enforce compile error upon nullability annotation violation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

**Background**

We have been developing public dynamic iOS / macOS framework. The framework is written in Objective-C, but it has full compatibility with Swift.

Recently, we have changed nullability annotation for one of our public API methods:

from

```
- (void)setServer:(nullable ABCLocation *)location;
```

to

```
- (void)setServer:(nonnull ABCLocation *)location;
```

, so developer would need to create `[ABCLocation default]` instance and pass it to new API.

**Question**

Now, we are concerned, how to enforce / notify developers to change their existed code around our new API?

When using the API with *Swift*, it seems to handle nullability pretty well by throwing an error.

*Objective-C*, though, generates a warning only when `nil` is passed, Xcode does nothing, when developers passes a `nullable` property to the method.

How do we enforce developers to change their API? What are the common practices here?

**UPD:**

We distribute the framework as a binary, built with *Release* configuration, where assertions are turned off.

**UPD #2:**

So far, we have accepted the reality when our API is used from Objective-C. However, we have implemented a "fail safe" behavior: if `nil` is passed, the method internally creates `[ABCLocation default]` instance and  passes it through implicitly.

Comment: "Xcode does nothing, when developers passes a nullable property to the method." Something else is wrong, you should get warnings if this was in fact the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating a warning when annotation is not met is a good practice. Making changes like `nullable` -> `nonnull` in APIs is not.

Comment: Could you please be move specific about "Making changes like `nullable` -> `nonnull` in APIs is not [a good practice]"?

Comment: I just meant that making breaking changes of doubtful usefulness in API is not a good idea generally

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for helping out! As I mentioned in **UPD #2**, we had added a "fail safe" behavior in order not to break things. Marking your answer as accepted, b/c it correlates with the final decision I have made.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice when you can't get the compiler to enforce an error (like in your instance) is to throw a runtime error. Something like:

```
- (void)setServer:(nonnull ABCLocation *)location    
{
    if (!location) {
        NSAssert(NO, @"Location must not be nil");
    }
```

Its not ideal but the combination of a compiler warning when nil is passed and a runtime error thrown on misuse should be pretty clear to developers using your framework incorrectly.

Comment: We distribute the framework in a form of binary built with *Release* configuration, where assertions are turned off. Forget to mention it. I've updated the question.